# Multiple item using for loop in bootstrap carousel slider

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to display two item at a time in one slide of bootstrap slider using php for loop please help me for that i have written the below code for that please suggest

```
for ($i=0;$i<=$num_logo-1;$i++){        
    $result_logo = db_fetch_row($qid_logo);
    if($i== 0 ) {
        echo "<div class=\"item active\" >\n";
        echo"<div class=\"col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12\" style=\"float:left; padding-right:10px; text-align:center;\">";
        echo"<img src=\"images/winner_logo/".$result_logo[3]."\" class=\"img-responsive center-block\"  ><br><b>".$result_logo[1]."</b>";
        if(($i+1) % 2 == 0) {
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<div class=\"item\" >\n";
        echo"<div class=\"col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12\" style=\"float:left; padding-right:10px; text-align:center;\">";
        echo"<img src=\"images/winner_logo/".$result_logo[3]."\" class=\"img-responsive center-block\"  ><br><b>".$result_logo[1]."</b>";
        echo"</div>";
        echo "</div>\n";    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use array chunk function

```
<?php foreach (array_chunk($array, 2, true) as $column){ ?>
  <div class="row"> <!--this will be outer area-->
      <?php foreach ($column as $item){ ?>
          <div class="col-md-6"> <!--this will be inner item area-->
              <p></p>
          </div>
      <?php } ?>
  </div> <!--this will be outer area closing-->
<?php } ?>
```

replace outer area with your bootstrap divs and inner area with your per item data...:)